# Trying to implement a countdowntimer in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, countdowntimer

I want to implement a timer in DOM but I don't want to use any Javascript. Is this actually possible?

I already have the code in Javascript but I would like to change it to DOM so that I don't have to activate JS.

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: What do you mean "change it to DOM"? Is it a homework?

Comment: "I don't want to use any Javascript" & "I already have the code in Javascript" This doesn't make any sense. Please post the code you have...

Comment: Switch to another programming language - thats the only option you have. The DOM isn't a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to reliably modify the Document Object Model is with JavaScript. DOM is just a structure for accessing parts of a webpage, nothing more.

So unless you have a vendetta against JavaScript and would rather using something like client side VBscript (IE only) you have to use JavaScript.

If you just want to get a similar effect you could try playing with CSS pseudo-elements which I doubt will cover your needs. Also CSS pseudo-elements aren't really part of the page so there are quirks; pseudo-element text cannot be selected for example.

In short, you must use JavaScript to "use" DOM, its a structure, not a language.

Comment: Thank you. That was the answer I thought which would come up. I'm not very good with Javascript but the problem is that I have to make a webpage useable without Javascript and I need the countdown timer.

Comment: You can use flash, but that wouldn't make any sense given your argument of having JavaScript enabled. People who disable JavaScript, probably won't have Flash enabled. Since HTML is static i'd strongly advice you to use JavaScript for such a task. You could warn your users that they have to enable JavaScript with the <noscript> tag

Comment: @Saebekassebil I don't know of how flash can modify the DOM. Or are you saying instead of DOM altogether?

Comment: Instead of DOM altogether, but again I don't recommend it, when it can so easily be achieved with JavaScript.